# Entity Framework Detach vs Remove

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Can someone explain what is the difference between those two? When is it better to use each of these methods and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Remove**: mark the entity to be deleted so when you do `SaveChanges` it's deleted from the db
- **Detach**: remove the entity from the `DbContext` change tracker so whatever you do with the entity `DbContext` doesn't notice. So when you do `SaveChanges` nothing happens with this entity

Comment: Thank you, and what about entry state = deleted?
My problem is that I have model with collection configured as cascade delete, yet when I remove the model I get foreign key violation, any idea why?

Comment: @S.Peter Please put this in a new question showing all code necessary to see what's going on.

Comment: @S.Peter there are lots of posts about deleting and collection, please search. Basically removing from collection just dissociates child entities instead of marking them as deleted so you get fk violation because FKs get 0. Cascade deleting let you delete the parent and once SaveChanges occurs all children will be deleted

Comment: @S.Peter if the question is answered it would be nice to Accept the answer. Regards